# Partial derivative of a point depending by two parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, partial-derivative

I have a point P which lies on a surface so that P=f(u,v) where u and v are the coordinates from the parametrization of the surface.

What kind of function is f so that it returns three values for the P point (x,y and z)? I can't figure that out

Besides, is it true that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial u}$ is a vector? I need some basic 3D algebra, if you don't want to explain it to me feel free to link material that may help to solve my doubts (for beginners please!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So you can write it coordinatewise as
$$
f(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)).
$$

Then you can differentiate coordinatewise:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u,v)=\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(u,v), \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}(u,v), \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}(u,v)\right).
$$
This is indeed a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.